# ACC EMEA - can't get EMEA Hub

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

When I ask a collection of Hubs, I don't receive ACC Hubs from EMEA (just BIM360 Hubs from US).

In my application, I ask for Hubs from the http request `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs`

I received well the BIM360 Hubs from US but not the ACC Hubs from EMEA.
In the response, a warning indicate:

```
warnings:{[
    {
        "Id": null,
        "HttpStatusCode": "403",
        "ErrorCode": "BIM360DM_ERROR",
        "Title": "Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM EMEA.",
        "Detail": "You don't have permission to access this API",
        "AboutLink": null,
        "Source": null,
        "meta": null
    }
]}
```

I use a 3-Legged Token with the good scopes (including 'data:read' for this request).
My user account can navigate in the Hub ACC platform (Admin account).

So how can I get the ACC Hub from EMEA ? Does I need to register my APS app in ACC like with BIM360 ? (I don't think so).

I have no more idea.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to obtain the Hubs in the EMEA region, you do need to register your ClientID in the Custom Integrations in your EMEA account. Keep in mind that we have different url's for US and EMEA Bim360 and ACC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jaime, but unfortunately, I can't register my App ClientID in the Custom Integrations Menu. This button is not present in the interface in EMEA account, unlike the US account. I will send you by email some interface captures.

Comment: Thanks, @Jaime for your support. The button has been added by Autodesk Team in the EMEA Admin Account. After App registration, I can get now the Hub. I close the subject.